# Vue Draggable Support for keeping item in From array?

Tags: vue.js, draggable

For this [Vue Draggable library](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) I have a use case where when I drag an item to another one I want the original item being dragged to stay in its array. In other words, I want to make a copy of it in the To array.

Is there support for this out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pull:'clone' options on the component

```
<draggable v-model="list" class="dragArea" :options="{group:{ name:'people',  pull:'clone', put:false }}">
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/t3m5krea/

Comment: Thanks, I saw the `onClone` / `clone` but not `pull`'s `clone`. And looks like just the `pull` is sufficient, so `put` is unnecessary.